# Show that no group has $D_n$ as its derived subgroup.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, dihedral-groups

(Yesterday I found an answer to this exact question by mistake and today I am not being able to find it again...)

I am asked to show that no group has $D_n$ as its derived subgroup. I am also given a hint, which reads

> Suppose $G$ is such that $G' = D_n$. Let $K < D_n$ be such that $K \cong \mathbb{Z}_n$ and show that $\varphi: G \to Aut(K)$, given by $\varphi(g) = c_g$, is a group homomorphism and study $\varphi(G^{(1)})$.

First of I am not sure if $\varphi(g) = c_g$ is conjugation by $g$. If it is, then I believe I proved it is indeed a group homomorphism:

$$\varphi(gh)(a) = ghah^{-1}g^{h-1} = g(hah^{-1})g^{-1} = (\varphi(g)\circ \varphi(h))(a)$$

I also know that if $\varphi$ is a homomorphism, then $\varphi(G^{(1)}) = \varphi(G)^{(1)}$ and thus we should have

$$\varphi(D_n) = \varphi(G)^{(1)}$$

and maybe the proof continues by showing that these two are actually different... Other than that, I have no clue as to how keep going.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $Aut(K)$ is abelian, since $K$ is cyclic.

Thus, the kernel of $\phi : G \to Aut(K)$ must contain $G'$.

Therefore,
$$\{e\} = \phi(G') = \phi(D_n)$$

therefore, conjugation by any element of $D_n$ acts as the identity on $K$. So $K \subseteq Z(D_n)$, But this is not true (for $n \ge 3$).

Comment: Because, for example, conjugation by the reflection gives $\sigma\rho\sigma = \rho^{-1} $?

Comment: @RGS Yes (assuming that $\rho$ is the rotation and $\sigma$ the reflection).